# Why does the np.where function also seem to work on values

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I'm trying to change the values of only certain values in a dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
dict_curr = {'a':2}
test['col2'] = np.where(test.col1 == 'a', test.col1.map(lambda x: dict_curr[x]), test.col2)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work because even though I'm looking only at the values in col1 that are 'a', the error says

```
KeyError: 'b'
```

Implying that it also looks at the values of col1 with values 'b'. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is originating from the `test.col1.map(lambda x: dict_curr[x])` part. You look up the values from `col1` in `dict_curr`, which only has an entry for `'a'`, not for `'b'`.

You can also just index the dataframe:

```py
test.loc[test.col1 == 'a', 'col2'] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `np.where` all of its parameters are evaluated first, and then the result is decided depending on the condition. So the dictionary is queried also for `'b'` and `'c'`, even if those values will be discarded later. Probably the easiest fix is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
dict_curr = {'a': 2}
test['col2'] = np.where(test.col1 == 'a', test.col1.map(lambda x: dict_curr.get(x, 0)), test.col2)
```

This will give the value `0` for keys not in the dictionary, but since it will be discarded later it does not matter which value you use.

Another easy way of getting the same result is:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
dict_curr = {'a': 2}
test['col2'] = test.apply(lambda x: dict_curr.get(x.col1, x.col2), axis=1)
```